# What is the terminology for "lemma of lemma"

Tags: terminology, article-writing

Let's say I need to prove a main theorem, to prove which I need three lemmas. Thus in writing the structure is as follows:

> Lemma 1
>
> *Proof*
>
> Lemma 2
>
> *Proof*
>
> Lemma 3
>
> *Proof*
>
> Theorem
>
> *Proof*

But if when proving Lemma 1, I need to prove another two results ("lemmas for the proof of a lemma"). Is there any standard terminology for this situation? It seems to me that calling them Lemmas makes the structure of the article messier.

Comment: I have seen "sub-lemma".

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, thanks! Is it a standard terminology?

Comment: You could use a Lemma to prove a Proposition which helps you to prove the Theorem

Comment: @Surb, sounds a good idea; thanks!

Comment: I would just use lemma.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thanks for your comment. It seems that everyone does not agree on this question, which makes me more confused...

Comment: @Zuriel The idea of Yuval is also good to me, but I never crossed a "sub-lemma" in my life. Another possibility is to merge the proofs of your two lemmas and make the proof in "two parts".

Comment: @Zuriel: there is nothing to be confused about, really. Different writers have different styles; the important thing is just to choose something that is clear, and that suits you, and stick with it.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, I am still a novice in writing mathematical papers; instead of creating a new style, I would still prefer to follow the majority...

Comment: I'd call them all lemma. If some lemma to lemma proofs are rally short, some migh even be called corollaries.

Comment: @Zuriel: that is a very sensible approach, and in cases where a clear convention exists, one should have a very good reason not to follow it. What I meant to get at with my previous comment is that, in this case, there does not seem to be any consensus, but that's ok: all you need to do is choose the style you like best, and stick with it.

Comment: As for my initial comment: I don't think sublemma is standard, but a quick Google shows that it is by no means uncommon (so you wouldn't be creating your own style); it has the added advantage of being self-explanatory. But I am not trying to advocate for it, just to give an option.

Comment: I would use either "sublemma" or "claim"; I think both are fairly common.

Comment: In addition to "sublemma" and "claim", I also saw "observation" being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Claim* to set it on a lower footing than a lemma, but it's really not a big deal.  One lemma can build on other lemmas.

The biggest distinction you want to make is between the results you consider broad and important (theorems), narrow but important for the proof of a theorem (lemmas), and immediate consequences of theorems (corollaries).